# java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to Connect to camera service

Tags: android, camera

I tried to make an app than can switch my camera flash on and off.
The code I have atm looks like this:

```
Camera flash;
Camera.Parameters params;

flash = Camera.open();
params = flash.getParameters();

params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);        
flash.setParameters(params);
```

And in the manifest xml:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"  

android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
          android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </permission>
```

Everytime I run the code, the app crashes at "flash = Camera.open();"  with this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to Connect to camera service

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Despite the formating issues with the manifest part I'd say that you have to use <uses-permission /> tags instead of <permission /> ones for the flashlight and the camera. 

Also to make this clear, please post the correctly formated manifest part (and probably the whole stacktrace, if this is a permission issue, there should be a hint before the exception in the logcat).

Answer (score 35):

To access the device camera, you must declare the CAMERA permission in your Android Manifest like this,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: thats not totally true, you don't need the uses-feature tag for accessing the camera: "Declared <uses-feature> elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's <uses-feature> declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application. "
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Answer (score 9):

You might have forgotten to call release in `onDestroy`

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually that problem is due to the missing camera request permission, as already said by other users.

But, just to register here another cause, if you try to open the camera using a cameraID that does not exist, you will receive that same error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to Connect to camera service

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the new request permission on android 6.x programmatically before.

```
 private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 555;

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();
        }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();
            } else {
                FragmentHelper.popFragment(getActivity(), null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```